# Counting how many script in SSIS have been completed

Tags: scripting, ssis, etl, data-warehouse

In SSIS package i have multiple scripts running within a job. At any given time i want to read how many scripts have been executed eg, 5/10 (50%) have been completed. Please tell how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no such functionality provided by SSIS to track progress of package execution.

It seems you need to write your own custom utility/application to implement same or use third party one.

There are few ways to do -

1. Using a switch called [/Reporting or /Rep of DTEXEC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx) at the command-line . For example:

> DTEXEC /F ssisexample.dtsx /Rep P > progress.txt

2.[Implement package logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138020.aspx) or [customize](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/06/11/SSIS_3A00_-Custom-Logging-Using-Event-Handlers.aspx) it.

3 . [Implement Event handler](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-event-handlers-basics/) on required executable. You can also use [OnPipelineRowsSent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141122.aspx) log of  Data Flow Task.

If you want to write your own application then below thread will provide nice starting point.

[How do you code the Package Execution Progress window in C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bad8a2e3-8a06-4bd5-8493-18c79d97fad3/how-do-you-code-the-package-execution-progress-window-in-c?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, we are using another software to monitor the jobs that are running. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CA_Workload_Automation_AE

You can also try to create your own application that runs on the background that checks that status of your jobs, through checking the logs.

Comment: thankyou for your reply. Indeed its a very good option but problem is where i work, they are not allowing me to use another program. The solution should be built in as in within SSIS.

Comment: @user3766523 if you are able to update all the existing SSIS, you can create one flat file connection, update that one after excel file for example if one job is finished, then one SSIS job only checks that excel file.